# datagridview get row value error "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index"

Tags: c#, datagridview

I just have this code that would get the value of the specific row in a datagridview. During the execution an exception message have been pop out. "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index".

Here is my sample code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < invoiceGridView.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(invoiceGridView[3, i].Value.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're iterating over `invoiceGridView.Columns.Count`, but then you're using `i` as the `rowIndex` parameter. The first parameter is the column index, not the second one:

```
dataGridView1[int columnIndex, int rowIndex]
```

Try this instead, which will display the value of each column in the 3rd row:

```
MessageBox.Show(invoiceGridView[i, 3].Value.ToString());
```